# Content appearing outside of hamburger navigation

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-float

I have a hamburger navigation, I know the code for the menu itself work as I copied out of the other pages on the same site. On this particular page when I click the button the drop down appears outside of the space it should appear, however when I hover over where the links should be the text is changed as if it were in the correct position. I have tried for hours to figure this out on my own, some things that I have tried have been clearing both the * and body margin/padding, re-organizing the code and a bunch of other tricks that I have read about...Nothing works. What is wrong with my code?

Markup :

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="mobile-nav">
      <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="responsive-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="mepage.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="resumepage.html">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="contactpage.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headtext">
      <h1>How you can contact me</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ewrap">
    <div class="elist">
      <h2>You can join my email list</h2>
      <div class="center">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
          <form action="//brettwray.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0019715a1627a714a1cca620c&amp;id=e0cbe16c08" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

              <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
              <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
              <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="b_0019715a1627a714a1cca620c_e0cbe16c08" tabindex="-1" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
      <p>I promise never to spam you, just to update you on my projects and the occasional picture of Dozer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <h2>Joining a list isn't your thing?</h2>
      <div id="envelope">
        <a href="mailto:brett@brettwray.com?Subject=Brettwray.com%20inquiry" target="_top"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-5x"></i></a>
      </div>
      <p>You can always <a href="mailto:brett@brettwray.com?Subject=Brettwray.com%20inquiry" target="_top">Email Me.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="social-header">
    <h2>Is email too old school for you?</h2>
    <h3>Then you can find me on social media.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <div class="facebook">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="insta">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="linkedin">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
body {
  background-color: rgba(189, 186, 186, 0.3);
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(189, 186, 186, 0.3);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7EC9B1;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 90px #7EC9B1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
  background: #fff url(http://i57.tinypic.com/2a796e0.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.menu-btn div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-top: -0.50em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-menu {
  display: none;
}

.expand {
  display: block !important;
  float: right;
}

.menu-btn {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
}

.responsive-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000222;
}

.responsive-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
  color: white;
}

.responsive-menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.responsive-menu li:hover {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.headtext {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.headtext h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.ewrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 440px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.elist {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid #7EC9B1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.email {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid #7EC9B1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.email h2,
.elist h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #7EC9B1;
}

.email p,
.elist p {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.email p {
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.email a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mc_embed_signup #mc-field-group {
  clear: left;
  font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe-form {
  padding: 20px;
}

div.mc-field-group {
  padding: 10px;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.button {
  background-color: #7EC9B1;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
}

#mc_embed_signup input.email {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
}

#social-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 720px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 820px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 20%;
  display: table;
}

#social-header h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #7EC9B1;
  text-align: center;
}

#social-header h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.facebook {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.insta {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.twitter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.linkedin {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.facebook:hover,
.insta:hover,
.twitter:hover,
.linkedin:hover {
  color: #7EC9B1;
}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
  })
})
```

Comment: A link to the code pen may also be helpful... [link](http://codepen.io/BrettWray/pen/EjWWXM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update following css :

```
.responsive-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, verdana, "trebuchet ms";
  color: white;
  /* added extra css rule */
  line-height:35px;
  height:35px;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

[updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyypo?editors=010)